# What does redirecting to an instance mean in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

What does  redirecting to a particular instance mean? I am aware of how the redirecting works.

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)
    if @user.save
      log_in @user
      flash[:success] = "Welcome to the Sample App!"
      redirect_to @user
    else
      render 'new'
    end
  end

  def edit
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  private

    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :email, :password,
                                   :password_confirmation)
    end
end
```

I understand the following ways of redirecting:

- `redirect_to :new` (redirect to new method and displaying the new.html.erb file)
- `redirect_to "show"`  (redirect to show.html.erb file or the path for show method)

but what does `redirect_to @user` mean? Which method and path are we are redirecting to?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the [redirect_to](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Redirecting.html#method-i-redirect_to) documentation, you will find this.

**Record** - The URL will be generated by calling `url_for` with the `options`, which will reference a named URL for that record.

Comment: what will be the named `url_for` for `@user` record?

Comment: @python It automagically figures it out based on the most logical route for that model, by default `user_path`.

Answer (score 3):

It's Rails "magic" for redirecting to the `#show` action for that `@user` using `GET`. You'll find similar things in default Rails forms as well, but for actions like `POST`.

Answer (score 3):

According to section [7.4.1](https://www.railstutorial.org/book/sign_up#sec-the_finished_signup_form) from Michael Hartl's *The Rails Tutorial*:

```
redirect_to @user
```

can be written instead of

```
redirect_to user_url(@user)
```

Quoting Michael Hartl:

> This is because Rails automatically infers from **redirect_to @user** that
>   we want to redirect to **user_url(@user)**.